# android translateAnimation setDuration() doesn't work

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I'm trying to create a translate animation to an imageView. The animation works but not according to the value I'm putting in the setDuration()

This is the code

```
/* flipping the images out of the screen */

float outOfScreenX = currentImageLocationX * DRAG_ACTION_SCREEN_BOUNDS_THREASHOLD;

float outOfScreenY = currentImageLocationY * DRAG_ACTION_SCREEN_BOUNDS_THREASHOLD;

            translate = new TranslateAnimation(0, outOfScreenX, 0, outOfScreenY);

            long velocity = Math.max(Math.abs((int) vTracker.getXVelocity()), Math.abs((int) vTracker.getYVelocity())) / 10;

            velocity = (long) Math.min(velocity, 200);

            translate.setDuration(velocity);
            translate.setFillAfter(true);
            mDragView.clearAnimation();
            mDragView.startAnimation(translate);

            imageStack.removeView(mOriginator);
```

The value of "velocity" derived from the vTracker, the speed of the user's touch on the view. It's always between 200-600 proximately, but the view moves much faster than this(and also a little flickering but this is another topic).

Comment: I have a similar problem for low duration values, but only on some devices. If I crank up the duration, it works. Did you happen to ever find an answer?

Comment: no I didn't, sorry. It was a long time ago so I don't remember exactly what I did there but I think that the duration didn't work because of fundamental error that I did. I might have putted the animated view inside the Window Manager and Window Manager does not supports animation.